# muon package manager can't find packages

Tags: apt, package-management, kde

I've a strange problem with muon package manager.

For a few days I've been trying to install packages (umlet for example) without success.

When I try to install anything muon says that it cant find the packages to install.

muon says for example, that it can't find the package "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjaxp1.3-java/libjaxp1.3-java_1.3.05-2ubuntu3_all.deb", despite the fact, that it does exist!

I did a KDE upgrade, I reinstalled MUON, cleared the `/var/lib/apt/lists` folder - nothing helps.

Today I decided to install umlet with the help of APT; and look: it works!

How can I fix MUON?

Answer (score 1):

ok, at last I found the answer which is very tricky:

I had used the KDE default browser "rekonq" to test public proxies. To do this I had had to change the proxy settings inside the browser app. And than after the trial I just put the browser aside and forgot about it.

BUT! rekonq changes the system settings if you change the proxy. And this change remained in the system and caused my problem. Very hard to find out what happened. I think it's generally a very bad idea, that the browser changes system settings.